# HTTPS issues in azure

Tags: node.js, azure, socket.io

I imported the git socket.io chat room project! The code works normally with `http = require ('http')` but when exchanging for `https = require ('https')` my server responds with error 500 http

```
var express = require('express')
  , app = express()
 // , http = require('http')
  , https = require('https')
  , fs = require('fs')

  , privateKey  = fs.readFileSync('HTTPS_Permissions/key.key', 'utf8')
  , certificate = fs.readFileSync('HTTPS_Permissions/cert.cert', 'utf8')
  , credentials = {key: privateKey, cert: certificate}
  , httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, app)

 // , httpServer = http.createServer(app)
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(httpsServer)

  //, port = process.env.PORT || 8080
  , port = process.env.PORT


  httpsServer.listen(port, function () {
    console.log('Server listening on port %d', port);
  });

//httpServer.listen(port);

// routing
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
```

Comment: The example from here,right? https://github.com/socketio/chat-example

Comment: @JayGong imported in azure portal this git --> https://github.com/fern4lvarez/socketiochatrooms

Comment: Does the project works fine locally? Have you checked whether the error resulted from project itself,not from azure? What actions have you tried?

Comment: @JayGong yes locally is work 100%, a newbie in azure... I'm putting aside https, I'm now testing http, I'm getting 404 error on the server. My project is in the 'public' folder and the 'app node' in the 'wwwroot' folder and I am not able to connect, it gives me the error 404. If I assign a virtual path directory 'socket.io' e directory  
physical path 'site\wwwroot\socket.io' in portal a azure, returns me error 403. How do I run the site in the subfolder along with the node / socket.io in the root folder?

Comment: @JayGong this example my directory structure --> https://i.imgur.com/w46czXG.png

Comment: Ok,I'll  test on my side.

Comment: @JayGong in the 'public\index.php' call the script `<script src="https://myproject.azurewebsites.net/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>`

Comment: @JayGong I just re-imported the git project .. I created a 'public' folder inside 'root' and I threw the 'index.html' from the git example into the 'public' folder. In the azure portal, I configured the virtual directory '/' for the physical directory 'site \ wwwroot \ public' and when I access the site I get error 'You do not have permission to view this directory or page.'

Comment: I do not understand why the git example runs 100% in the 'root' folder and by putting 'index.html inside the 'public' folder I get error = /

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed the [project](https://github.com/fern4lvarez/socketiochatrooms) you shared in the comment,it works on my side.

[image]

***web.config***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
     This configuration file is required if iisnode is used to run node processes behind
     IIS or IIS Express.  For more information, visit:

     https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/blob/master/src/samples/configuration/web.config
-->

<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <!-- Visit http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2013/11/14/introduction-to-websockets-on-windows-azure-web-sites.aspx for more information on WebSocket support -->
    <webSocket enabled="false" />
    <handlers>
      <!-- Indicates that the server.js file is a node.js site to be handled by the iisnode module -->
      <add name="iisnode" path="app.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode"/>
    </handlers>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <!-- Do not interfere with requests for node-inspector debugging -->
        <rule name="NodeInspector" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^app.js\/debug[\/]?" />
        </rule>

        <!-- First we consider whether the incoming URL matches a physical file in the /public folder -->
        <rule name="StaticContent">
          <action type="Rewrite" url="public{REQUEST_URI}"/>
        </rule>

        <!-- All other URLs are mapped to the node.js site entry point -->
        <rule name="DynamicContent">
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True"/>
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="app.js"/>
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>

    <!-- 'bin' directory has no special meaning in node.js and apps can be placed in it -->
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <hiddenSegments>
          <remove segment="bin"/>
        </hiddenSegments>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>

    <!-- Make sure error responses are left untouched -->
    <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />

    <!--
      You can control how Node is hosted within IIS using the following options:
        * watchedFiles: semi-colon separated list of files that will be watched for changes to restart the server
        * node_env: will be propagated to node as NODE_ENV environment variable
        * debuggingEnabled - controls whether the built-in debugger is enabled

      See https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/blob/master/src/samples/configuration/web.config for a full list of options
    -->
    <iisnode watchedFiles="web.config;*.js"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

If you throw the `index.html` into public folder which is created by yourself under `wwwroot/` directly, you need to add the below code into your code based on this [article](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html).

```
app.use(express.static('public'))
```

[image]

I tested for that.

[image]

---

Update Answer:

I also turn on the `Web Sockets` Option.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for helping me! But I have not been able to run the app yet. I'm having a 403 error -> https://i.imgur.com/X8H6afz.png - on `site\wwwroot` I have the `web.conf`, `app.js` files. My root directory structure and public -> https://i.imgur.com/rf6OaC8.png. And finally my `app.js` -> https://i.imgur.com/4ADqvZl.png

Comment: I changed the application configurations. But, now showed this new error  -> https://i.imgur.com/2P8Fx5P.png Error 405 the `POST` method not allowed. I'm hopeless =/

Comment: yes! websockets already turn on... the problem persist.. =/ .... I had an idea.. put the entire project all in the `root` folder. But I need to configure `web.config` for the node and for php in the same folder. Is there a way to merge this into a single `web.config`?

Comment: @FábioZangirolami Sorry for the delay, the static file in the example is html,you mean you modify it as php?

Comment: my application has no route to php files. As the node is not manipulable .phps .. I only have route to directories .... I was able to solve my problem by doing this setup on the azure portal -> https://i.imgur.com/KB1YZJL.png